# Funções Kotlin - Retornando valor inicial mesmo tendo mudado durante a função

Tags: funções, firebase, kotlin

Olá, bom dia. Eu tenho uma função que faz uma requisição de usuários do banco de dados do firebase e retorna uma lista dos mesmos, eu identifiquei que a lista não muda fora do método onCompleteListener mas então como recuperar e retornar a lista modificada no método?

Segue a função :

```
private fun loadUsers(list: MutableList<User>): MutableList<User> {
        val requestUsers = dbReference.collection("users").get()

        requestUsers.addOnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                it.result.documents.map { user ->
                    val newUser =
                        User(
                            user.get("name").toString(),
                            user.getString("email").toString(),
                            user.getString("urlPhoto").toString()
                        )
                    list.add(newUser)
                    Log.i("Log1", list.size.toString())
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), getString(R.string.success), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
        Log.i("Log2", list.size.toString())
        return list
    }
```

Para identificar o meu problema, coloquei dois logs na função e esses são os resultados.

Log1 -> Imagem [image: Log1]

Log2 -> Imagem [image: Log2]

Desde já agradeço a ajuda de todos, é provável que seja um erro grotesco porém eu estou agarrado a algum tempo nesse problema então resolvi postar aqui.

Comment: Procure estudar sobre funções assíncronas e coroutines, pois este é seu problema.
O _addOnCompleteListener_ vai ser executado assincronamente sem pausar a execução do código restante. Ou seja, o código de dentro vai ser executado somente quando o listener for completado. Enquanto isso o Log que está fora (Log2) vai ser executado em sequencia, quando a lista ainda não foi alterada. O _addOnCompleteListener_ só vai adicionar uma ação que vai ser executada em um momento futuro.

Comment: Entendi, então a única forma de resolver isso seria transformando a lista em uma lista observável com o Livedata ou Flow ? ou há alguma forma dessa função retornar o valor apenas após a execução do onCompleteListener?

Comment: Não sei afirmar se existe outra forma pra atender este seu request, mas eu utilizaria sim um LiveData ou o Flow como você comentou. Dessa forma teu método _loadUsers_ seria apenas chamado (Sem retornar nada) e você aplicaria as mudanças necessárias quando o LiveData lhe retornar um novo valor.